# Read Text file only first and last column, latter write last column with TAG NAme

Tags: python

I have  a list.txt file with content as follows:

```
1535    2015-22-12  0010.dcm
1530    2015-22-12  0013.dcm
1531    2015-22-12  0014.dcm
..
..
..
```

Now i want to read only one row lets say first row and column 1st and third for eg: read 1535 and oo10.dcm into two different string variables. I will use os.join to create path from these variables.

DO Some operation on the file...

and then after reading header of the .dcm file in first row, i would like to add 4th column with a tag value.

Hence at the end the txt file should look something like this:

```
1535    2015-22-12  0010.dcm    lab1
1530    2015-22-12  0013.dcm    lab2
1531    2015-22-12  0014.dcm    lab3
..
..
..
```

How can this be performed in python ?

any hints ?

Comment: I would do it by reading the whole file and then you manipulate strings, i.e. you can split a line by spaces and you get the columns, etc.

Comment: Your title does not really match the description in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator
import csv
import os
import string


vals = operator.itemgetter(0,2)
lab = string.Template("lab${n}")

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for labnum,row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'), 1):
        num, fname = vals(row)
        fpath = os.path.join(num, fname)
        # do file operations with fpath
        row.append(lab.substitute(n=labnum))

        outfile.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import re

with open('list.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        fields = re.split(r' +', line)
        ... do stuff with fields[0] and fields[2] ...
        print(line + ' ' + tag)
```

Comment: Using the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) module with the `inplace` option, you can kind-of simultaneously read and write the file.

Comment: To most part this works except 'fields[0]' and 'fields[1]' gives me complete first row from txt file. it gives me output as 'firstcolumn\tsecondword\thord_string' while i am looking for fields[0] = first_column @Mad Wombat

Comment: Ah, I thought you had spaces there. Try to use \s instead of literal space in the regular expression in re.split()